# The use of cin.get() to read a character(s)

Tags: c++, c++11

Can someone explain to me how cin.get() works below. My thinking  is that cin.get() takes in a character from the keyboard (when you type it), assigns it to character1, then compares it to EOF, if this comparison is not equal, it prints it, then goes back to the while loop and does thesame until the EOF character is entered. What I expected to see is characters printed each time I enter them until EOF is entered but I am suprised to see that the program takes in characters until I enter EOF then it prints them all.

```
      int character1; 
      cout << "Before input, cin.eof() is " << cin.eof()<< endl
         << "Enter a sentence followed by end-of-file:" << endl;
      while ((character1 = cin.get()) != EOF)   
             cout.put(character1);

        cout << "\nEOF in this system is: " << character << endl;
```

Comment: Your question is really not clear, but EOF is not the sequence  of characters "EOF" - it's a (to simplify greatly) special keypress, such as Ctrl-D or Ctrl-Z, depending on platform.

Comment: According to this:
http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_istream/get

cin.get() shouldn't give you an EOF character when it hits an EOF. Which I think would mean you shouldn't really reach your != EOF condition.

Comment: Yes, the comparison should be using `!= std::istream::traits_type::eof()` (aka `!= std::char_traits<char>::eof()`) instead of `!= EOF`. A better option is to use the other overloaded version of `get()` that returns a `char` by reference instead: `while (cin.get(character1)) { ... }`, but then the final value of `character1` will be indeterminate once the loop breaks.

Comment: I got where my misunderstanding was coming from. It was a mistake on my part. Thanks all for the input

Comment: I was a bit surprised to see on Linux it does not work a character at a time on the terminal, until I remembered `stty` and `termios`. Linux consoles are a terminal, and they pretend to be a serial terminal from the 1970s. Their default mode is line by line. So no input is actually sent until you press Return. Unless you run `stty -icanon`, or use the functions in `man termios` to turn off ICANON mode. But warning, once out of ICANON mode you cannot use Ctrl-D for end of file.

Answer (score 1):

EOF/cin.eof() are not the same as the ASCII/tty EOF character(s). In both cases, the value is meaningful only in context, and may not actually exist otherwise.

On Windows EOF is signaled with Ctrl+Z.
On *nixen, it is signaled with Ctrl+D.

You cannot print it to the terminal either way. Tell the user to press the correct keys. And remember, the value of `EOF` has absolutely no relation to anything in the input stream (except being unrepresentable as a valid character value).

You see no output until you signal EOF because terminal input is, by default, line-buffered. Try pressing Enter during your input sequence to see the effect. If you wish to play with unbuffered input then that is a (lenghty) answer to another question.

Comment: Thanks Duthomhas. I understood everything now